# Maui Flyout Page iOS Exception When IsPresented = True

Tags: ios, .net, maui

I think this is a bug within the .NET Maui framework but wondered if anybody has a workaround.

Visual Studio 2022 17.6.6, Empty Maui App (NET 6.0) with the following three xaml content pages added (and App.xaml.cs modified to launch the flyout directly on load).

**Flyout.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<FlyoutPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp1"
        x:Class="MauiApp1.Flyout"
        FlyoutLayoutBehavior="Popover" 
        NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
        Title="Flyout"
        IsPresented="True">
<FlyoutPage.Flyout>
    <local:FlyoutMenu x:Name="flyoutPage" />
</FlyoutPage.Flyout>
<FlyoutPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
        <x:Arguments>
            <local:FlyoutContent />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</FlyoutPage.Detail>
```

**FlyoutMenu.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.FlyoutMenu"
             Title="FlyoutMenu"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label Text="Menu" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**FlyoutContent.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.FlyoutContent"
             Title="FlyoutContent"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">
    <VerticalStackLayout BackgroundColor="Black">
        <Label  Text="CONTENT" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="White" />
        <ImageButton Clicked="OnMenuButtonClicked" Source="list_white.png" />
        <ImageButton Clicked="OnHomeButtonClicked" Source="house_fill_white.png" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Running on iOS Simulator (iPhone 14 16.4), the `IsPresented=True` within Flyout.xaml causes the following exception:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object.'

It runs as expected when false, and both true and false work fine on Android.

Many Thanks :)

Comment: what does the stack trace show?

Comment: 1) *"and App.xaml.cs modified to launch the flyout directly on load"* - the problem may be here. Show that code. 2) If you go back to original app.xaml.cs code, does the null exception still occur?

Comment: Thanks Jason and ToolmakerSteve, it seems that on iOS, the flyoutpage doesn't get loaded into the stack before IsPresented is executed (stack trace), hence the accepted answer which handles the setting OnAppearing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce this and you may raise an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues).

Workaround:

1.Set **IsPresented** property in OnAppearing method with a delay:

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    await Task.Delay(10);
    this.IsPresented = true;     
}
```

and delete **IsPresented="True"** in xaml

2.Use [.NET MAUI Shell flyout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/flyout) as an alternative.

Hope it works!